# Avoid Distractions

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Got this puzzle from my colleague, which he says he made it and says use whatever means to solve, so no problem with posting here.

Trying to solve this puzzle but unable to get with it.

[image]

Hint 1:

> Avoid distractions

Hint 2:

> Hidden text is a quote

Hint 3:

> The hidden text does not use all characters available, and it has no spaces

Comment: Hi Abdul, and welcome to Puzzling :) Where is this puzzle from, please? All puzzles from elsewhere need to have their source accredited or they may end up being closed. Also, do you have any ideas about this puzzle yourself? What have you tried so far? This would be useful for us to know... Thanks!

Comment: @Stiv yes its a puzzle given by one of colleagues, and we have been trying to solve it.

Comment: Are you sure you've given everything involved for this puzzle? Some bits of information, like the name of an image or description on the file, text in the email etc etc could be relevant.

Comment: @LioElbammalf yes I am sure, thats what he only gave those 3 hints are all we got

Comment: The hidden text is a quote (Hint 2) but it has no spaces (Hint 3)? So, it is a one-word quote? @AbdulKawee

Comment: @SamRoy that's all i got, and it might be one word quote.

Comment: New hint is that its going to be a complete sentence but without spaces like, ThisIsStackOverflow @Stiv

Comment: Thanks for the update Abdul. If you or your colleagues manage to crack it before anyone here, do feel free to post an answer explaining it as I'm sure people will want to know!

Comment: @Stiv yes sure why not, will share if i am able to crack it

Comment: @Stiv have posted answer below, do check :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We were unable to solve this puzzle, so our colleague who made this puzzle gave us the answer.

The answer is

> **"BETHESMARTESTPERSONINTHEROOM"**
>
>  **"BE THE SMARTEST PERSON IN THE ROOM"**
>
>  [image]

Comment: Ah, that's actually quite cool! Nice mechanism. Thanks for sharing the answer - always happy when a puzzle is closed off nicely! +1

Comment: Definitely cool! I can't figure out if the wingdings play a part in the logic of solving it, or if they are just placeholders?

Comment: Is it obtained by putting alternate black and white letters until e meaningful sentence is formed? Or any other analysis was necessary?